# Report grouped in Axapta 3.0

Tags: report, axapta

I need to generate a report that groups by two fields the records of a table in an Axapta 3.0. The source table I have has this structure:

[image]

And the report I want to get looks like this:

[image]

What sections and properties should the report have in order to create such a design? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you have backing tables for the fields 'LOTE' and 'DIARIO' then the easy option is to use them, the query should look like this, all inner joined:

- LoteTable

  - DiarioTable

    - YourTable

Remember to set `Relations` to `Yes` on the two first tables (or define the relations your self).

If you do not have backing tables, you can create them as views on your table.
The LoteTable view should contain the following fields:

- Lote
- Proveedor
- CountOfRecId (Aggregation Count)

The CountOfRecId field will make the view a group by on the first two fields.

Comment: Thanks Jan for your help. I'll try it out but I think it's best to create section groups for different groups and distribute the fields in them.